# HTML/CSS Avoid starting textfield on a new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

I'm using the bootstrap framework and i am trying to make it fluid, so it views "perfect" on every device. However i am currently experiencing a problem which i can't solve. The textfield starts on a new line at some point when you resize it. (Live Demo: http://veiling.jamieknoef.nl, the login textfields) It should stay in line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When it goes onto a new line it's really small. Probably so small that no real device would display it at that width. You're only seeing it going onto a new line because you're manually resizing your browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.login { min-width: 140px; }
```

That being said. Once the screen starts to get that narrow you need to look at possiby rearranging your layout as its going to have all sorts of problems on smaller devices - which is where [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) come in.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. One of my colleges told me to put the icon and textfield within a div. This could solve the problem, i haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Jamie - I believe they were already within a div. That being .login

Comment: Basically if you want the icon and text input to always fit within the area you need to make their widths fluid as well. That includes the icon image which is currently a fixed width. Once you work out the right percentage to set those icons' widths you'll be good to go